DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first on Angular
I am trying to play sound on refresh the page.
this is my code.
HTML File:
<audio #notificationAudio
palysinline
src="./../../../../assets/notification-26017.mp3">
</audio>

TS File:
@ViewChild('notificationAudio') notificationAudioEle: ElementRef
playSound() {
    // const notificationAudio = new Audio();
    // notificationAudio.src = "./../../../../assets/notification-26017.mp3";
    // notificationAudio.load();
    // notificationAudio.play();
    if(this.notificationAudioEle && this.notificationAudioEle.nativeElement){
      //this.notificationAudioEle.nativeElement.src = "./../../../../assets/notification-26017.mp3"
      this.notificationAudioEle.nativeElement.play()
    }

It's successfully play on first time but not on second time it's gives te below error.

DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

Can anyone suggest what I am missing here?
It's need to play on all time refresh the page.

A side note: you have a typo, palysinline
